# I wrote a merge sort but it ends up in an infinite loop

Tags: python, list, loops, sorting, infinite-loop

If the break rule is true in the first round, the program stops, but when it gets into the loop, it never stops

```
def mSort(liste):
    mSortHelp(liste, 0, len(liste)-1)
return liste

def mSortHelp(liste, first, last):
    if first < last:
        mid = (first+last)//2
        mSortHelp(liste, mid, last)
        mSortHelp(liste, fist, mid)
        merge(liste, first, mid, last)
    return liste

def merge(liste, first, mid, last):
    LeftList = liste[first:mid]
    RightList =lListe[mid:last+1]
    i=j=0
    for k in range (first, last):
        if LeftList[i] <= RightList[j]:
            liste[k] = LeftList[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            liste[k] = RightList[j]
            j+=1
    return liste

print(mSort(liste))
```

I hope somebody can help fix my infinite loop and give a sorted list (by merge sort) back.

Comment: Simplified, focused the title and tidied up the question in general

Answer (score 2):

First, infinit loop is caused by `if first < last:`, for example, if first=2, last=3, it will never break through it, if you change it to `first < last-1`, it will cause another problem, two len list will remain unsort. So the best way to solve this problem is make last no include, like `[first, last)`.

And there are other problems in your program, such as syntax problem, index out of range in merge, and other problems.
I have fixed them with comment:

```
def mSort(liste):
    # change the last index
    # mSortHelp(liste, 0, len(liste) - 1)
    mSortHelp(liste, 0, len(liste))
    return liste

def mSortHelp(liste, first, last):
    # here is the key point causes infinit loop, such as first=2 last = 3
    # if first < last:
    if first < last - 1:
        mid = (first + last) // 2
        mSortHelp(liste, mid, last)
        mSortHelp(liste, first, mid)
        merge(liste, first, mid, last)
    return liste


def merge(liste, first, mid, last):
    LeftList = liste[first:mid]
    # change the last index
    # RightList = liste[mid:last + 1]
    RightList = liste[mid:last]
    i = j = 0

    print(LeftList, RightList)
    # here should be last, which means [first, last+1)
    for k in range(first, last):
        # here will cause "IndexError: list index out of range", if i or j reach the end
        # if LeftList[i] <= RightList[j]:
        if i < len(LeftList) and j < len(RightList):
            if LeftList[i] <= RightList[j]:
                liste[k] = LeftList[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                liste[k] = RightList[j]
                j += 1
        # when one list reach the end  
        else:
            if i < len(LeftList):
                liste[k] = LeftList[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                liste[k] = RightList[j]
                j += 1
    print(liste[first: last])
    # return is not necessary here, has been changed by parameter reference
    # return liste
```

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Answer (score 1):

Example code where reaching the end of either sub-list is handled in the main merge loop, followed by a break, (instead of handling the copy after the loop).

```
def mergesort(a,beg,end):
    if (end-beg) > 1:
        mid=(beg+end)//2
        mergesort(a,beg,mid)
        mergesort(a,mid,end)
        merge(a,beg,mid,end)
def merge(a,beg,mid,end):
    left = a[beg:mid]
    right = a[mid:end]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = beg   
    while True:
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            a[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
            if(i < len(left)):
                continue
            a[k:end] = right[j:len(right)]
            break
        else:
            a[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
            if(j < len(right)):
                continue
            a[k:end] = left[i:len(left)]
            break
```